# SAPUI5: javascript code in xml fragment

Tags: javascript, xml, fragment, sapui5

I'm quite new to it and like to know the following. I'd like to have a feedback/rating opening in a dialog in a/n (xml) fragment. For that I want to use the code from here: [Consuming the Feedback Service Via a Browser](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?67a37dcbef0e461b8e8b2b23cc279c2c.html)
The question is: How do I incorporate this (javascript) code into an xml fragment like this (other solutions welcome, js/html fragment?):

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
 xmlns="sap.m"
 xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Dialog
title="Feedback"
class="sapUiPopupWithPadding" >
<content>
           .....  
</content>
<endButton>
  <Button text="Cancel" app:dialogType="Std2" press="onDialogCloseButton" />
</endButton>
```

thx

Answer (score 2):

A fragment uses the controller of the view which created it. You can put your logic in a function there.

So if you have Home.view.xml which creates a Rating.fragment.xml, you can use Home.controller.js to add the fragment logic.